# Permissions do not allow pasting files in this directory

Tags: partitioning, permissions, hard-drive, gparted, disk-usage

I'm using Tower PC with 500GB SSD & 1 TB HDD, installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on the SSD, The 1TB HDD I'm not able to use, while copy paste a file from SSD to HDD it says **"Permissions do not allow pasting files in this directory"**. Only using Ubuntu OS.

Response received during the copy paste:

[image]

And here for you to look at my SSD & HDD in gparted

View of my gparted Disk of HDD:

[image: View of my gparted Disk of HDD]

and View of my gparted Disk of SSD:

[image: View of my gparted Disk of SSD]

HDD "in terminal"

```
sudo gdisk /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

The protective MBR's 0xEE partition is oversized! Auto-repairing.

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
```

Have a look at the Properties - Permissions of the HDD:

[image: Properties - Permissions of the HDD]

**I do need to utilize the 1TB HDD for accessing files such Documents, Images, Videos with read, write** etc., Please help me to resolve this I'm a beginner in Linux and Ubuntu OS

Comment: no expert on this, suggestion - have you tried copying and pasting when using your file manager with root privileges? if that works, that could be a temporary workaround. I also note that your SSD is EXT4 while the 1TB HDD is NTFS, not sure if that is (part) of the problem? obviously reformatting the 1TB drive to EXT4 will lose you all the data on it? but then you say you only use Linux on this PC... unless you make some space in the 1TB HDD and create a new EXT4 Partition within it to see what happens -ie if you then can copy and paste into the EXT4 Partition?

Comment: Sounds like the HDD is locked by Windows because it was shutdown with Fast Boot enabled or simply hibernated. Can you turn off Fast Boot and boot the HDD into Windows? Then shutdown fully. Should work then.

Answer (score 0):

It happened with my machine as well. I have windows and ubuntu dual boot.
I could only write in my HDD from windows and not from ubuntu (read only mode). I had to completely shut down the windows before switching to ubuntu.
I just turned off windows fast restart option from control panel and turned off hibernate with cmd. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

This extract from the NTFS-3G manual explains what has probably happened.

On computers which can be dual-booted into Windows or Linux, Windows has to be fully shut down before booting into Linux, otherwise the NTFS file systems on internal disks may be left in an inconsistent state and changes made by Linux may be ignored by Windows.

So, Windows may not be left in hibernation when starting Linux, in order to avoid inconsistencies. Moreover, the fast restart feature available on recent Windows systems has to be disabled. This can be achieved by issuing as an Administrator the Windows command which disables both hibernation and fast restarting :

powercfg /h off
If either Windows is hibernated or its fast restart is enabled, partitions on internal disks are forced to be mounted in read-only mode.

Hope this helps

Edit:

Just noticed your 1TB appears to be empty. If that is the case and you don’t need to access it from Windows the simplest solution is to just reformat it to ext4.